# UIStackView not showing as expected

Tags: swift, constraints, uistackview

I want to add a `UIStackView` of log in buttons to my app, and so I added this code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


        SignInButtonsStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
        SignInButtonsStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10)
        SignInButtonsStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 10)
        SignInButtonsStackView.spacing = 5


        SignInButtonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(FacebookSignInButton)
        SignInButtonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(GoogleSignInButton)

    }
```

I am setting the `UIStackView`'s constraints first and then adding the buttons.

My goal is to be able to add more sign in buttons in the future while adding minimum code to do so.

This is what I get :

[image]

Which is not only not same width, but the height is messed up too.

How can I make sure all items in my UIStackView are of same width, height and spacing ? How do I fix this view to look fine ?

### Edit

I have this in debug window:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288700 UILayoutGuide:0x6000007b0760'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom == UIStackView:0x7f9b04d15420.bottom + 187   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288ac0 V:|-(499)-[UIStackView:0x7f9b04d15420]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9b04d166e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290f40 GIDSignInButton.height == 10   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9b04d076e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028cd50 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[GIDSignInButton]-(0)-|   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9b04d076e0, '|':UIStackView:0x7f9b04d15420 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028bb80 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f9b04d15420.top == FBSDKLoginButton:0x7f9b04d0a4d0'Continue with Facebook'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c00028ad20 'UISV-fill-equally' GIDSignInButton.height == FBSDKLoginButton:0x7f9b04d0a4d0'Continue with Facebook'.height   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9b04d076e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000288610 'UISV-spacing' V:[FBSDKLoginButton:0x7f9b04d0a4d0'Continue with Facebook']-(5)-[GIDSignInButton]   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9b04d076e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028d1b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f9b04d166e0.height == 736   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000288840 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000007b0760'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9b04d166e0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000290f40 GIDSignInButton.height == 10   (active, names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9b04d076e0 )>
```

Comment: Try SignInButtonsStackView.alignment = .fill

Comment: I added .fill , that did not affect the view in any way...

Comment: `SignInButtonsStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x` is not a constraint. You are also adding new constraints after every layout and you will end up with tens of duplicated constraints after a while. **Don't do** such things in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set height constraint of `UIStackView`. Just set height constraint of `UIButton's` in `UIStackView` and distribution to "Equal spacing" in `UIStackView`.

Comment: I am not setting a height constraint for UIStackView. only center, leading and trailing. How would you go on to doing what you said ?

Comment: As I said, you need to set height constraints for every UIButton you add in UIStackView.

Comment: I added FacebookSignInButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true (Same for GoogleSignInButton) and nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add `SignInButtonsStackView.distribution = .fillEqually` to get equal height for your buttons and `SignInButtonsStackView.alignment = .fill` in order to get same width.

Unfortunately how the buttons will behave depends on internal constraint their view may have. I would suggest to check the console for any log related to "unsatisfiable constraints" (setting a symbolic breakpoint for `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` may be useful https://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/).

Comment: @Ofri can you see any problem in the log console? Do you have any unsatisfiable constraint error?

Comment: The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-10-13 06:03:40.341356-0700 App[8030:168796] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Comment: Ok, can you see which constraints are impossible to satisfy? Both buttons could have some internal constraints making it impossible to create both same height and same width.

You should find more information in the debugger console.

Comment: Maybe these ones ?

(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002915d0 V:[UIImageView:0x7f9b04d41480]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7f9b04d3fca0'Gal Abir']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000292ac0 V:[UIImageView:0x7f9b04d41480]-(100)-[UILabel:0x7f9b04d3fca0'Gal Abir']   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000292ac0 V:[UIImageView:0x7f9b04d41480]-(100)-[UILabel:0x7f9b04d3fca0'Gal Abir']   (active)>

Comment: The one you linked is about a 100pt vertical space between a label and an image view… I think this specific may not be related to the buttons issue. Are there any other errors involving `UIStackView` and/or some of the buttons? An other approach I would suggest is to try to using the view debugger in Xcode (Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy while your app is running and in the login screen) and look around for unsatisfied constraint.

Comment: 1) I am not sure how to view hierarchy... I never debugged this way before...
2) I added an "Edit" with something that might look more relevant :)

Comment: In 1) I mean I don't know where the "Debug" is ... So that I can then click View Debugging etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181807/discussion-between-tom-139-and-ofri).